# cv2.FitEllipse errors. Why does one data set work and not the other?

Tags: python, ellipse

I am trying to use cv2.FitEllipse to fit an ellipse to data using the following python code:

```
 def getContours_test(clusters):
    copy_clusters=clusters.copy()
    int_cnts=[]
    for label in np.unique(clusters):
            mask = np.zeros(clusters.shape, dtype="uint8")
            mask[clusters == label] = 255
            cnts, hierarchy = \
                    cv2.findContours(mask.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
            int_cnts.append(cnts)
    list_contours=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(int_cnts))
    return copy_clusters, list_contours


def getEllipse_test(clusters, list_contours):
    for index,cnt in enumerate(list_contours):
            map_ellipse=np.ones(clusters.shape).astype(np.uint8)
            cimg = np.zeros_like(clusters)
            cv2.drawContours(cimg, list_contours, index, color=255, thickness=-1)
            ellipse=cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
            cv2.ellipse(map_ellipse,ellipse,(255,0,0))
    return map_ellipse

test_result, test_contours = getContours_test(test)
test_ellipse = getEllipse_test(test_result,test_contours)
mpl.contourf(test_result)
mpl.contour(test_ellipse)
mpl.show()
```

this first data set yields an answer:

```
 test2=np.zeros((400,1000))
 test2[240:260,110:120]=1
 test2[260:265,117:134]=1
 test2[265:270,134:155]=1
```

however when using this data I get the error at the bottom:

```
test=np.zeros((500,500))
test[   30      ,       219     ]=1
test[   40      ,       238     ]=1
test[   50      ,       250     ]=1
test[   60      ,       259     ]=1
test[   70      ,       266     ]=1
test[   80      ,       272     ]=1
test[   90      ,       277     ]=1
test[   100     ,       282     ]=1
test[   110     ,       285     ]=1
test[   120     ,       289     ]=1
test[   130     ,       291     ]=1
test[   140     ,       294     ]=1
test[   150     ,       296     ]=1
test[   160     ,       297     ]=1
test[   170     ,       298     ]=1
test[   180     ,       299     ]=1
test[   190     ,       300     ]=1
test[   200     ,       300     ]=1
test[   210     ,       300     ]=1
test[   220     ,       299     ]=1
test[   230     ,       298     ]=1
test[   240     ,       297     ]=1
test[   250     ,       296     ]=1
test[   260     ,       294     ]=1
test[   270     ,       291     ]=1
```

error message:

```
  error: (-201:Incorrect size of input array) There should be at least 5 points to fit the ellipse in function 'cv::fitEllipseNoDirect'
```

why does one data set work and not  the other?